# SQL Query is showed several times instead of once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have SQL query which should calculate an expression and show it

Here's the query

`SELECT (classes.amount_of_students - (SELECT COUNT(id_class) FROM classes_students WHERE id_class = 1)) AS free_playces FROM classes INNER JOIN classes_students ON classes.id_class = classes_students.id_class;`

Here are the tables:

`CREATE TABLE classes_students (
    id_class SERIAL REFERENCES classes (id_class),
    id_student SERIAL REFERENCES student (id_student),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_class, id_student)
);`

`CREATE TABLE classes (
    id_class SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    amount_of_hours VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    amount_of_students VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    id_subject SERIAL REFERENCES subject (id_subject),
    id_teacher SERIAL REFERENCES teacher (id_teacher)
);`

Here's data in `classes` table:

`id_class | amount_of_hours | amount_of_students | id_subject | id_teacher 
----------+-----------------+--------------------+------------+------------
        1 | 180             | 9                  |          1 |          2
        2 | 12              | 9                  |          2 |          1`

And `classes_students`:

`id_class | id_student 
----------+------------
        1 |          1
        2 |          2
        1 |          3`

The result is:

`

### free_places

```
        7
        7
        7
```

`

I don't understand why it is sown 3 times. I need to show it only once. How can I solve this problem and why it is happening? I added distinct, but I think that it isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `JOIN` in the outer query.  Also, you should be matching the class in the inner query to the class in the outer query.  This is called a *correlated subquery*:

```
SELECT (c.amount_of_students -
        (SELECT COUNT(id_class)
         FROM classes_students cs
         WHERE cs.id_class = c.id_class
        ) 
       ) as free_places
FROM classes c
WHERE c.id_class = 1
```